# Нахождение уникальных строк в txt с python

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

Время от времени сканирую сеть и сохраняю ip в txt файл в формате:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
10.0.0.5
```

Мне надо сравнивать два последних файла и выбрать из второго только новые ip, которых нет в первом. ip не сортированы и идут в разброс.

Вот как я приблизительно вижу решение, но оно не работает, возвращает все ip из второго файла:

```
import re

with open("data/ips.txt") as prev_ip, open("data/ips1.txt") as cur_ip:
    for line in cur_ip:

        str_line = str(line)
        if re.search( str_line , str(prev_ip)):
            pass
        else:
            # pass
            print(line)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так с этим кодом и есть ли более быстрый или красивый способ это сделать.

Вот еще один неработающий пример

```
with open("data/ips.txt") as prev_ip, open("data/ips1.txt") as cur_ip:
    for line in cur_ip:

        str_line = str(line)
        if  line.strip() in prev_ip.readlines():
            pass
        else:
            # pass
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_line = str(line)` - так вы превращаете строку в список символов этой строки, это явно не то, что вам нужно.

Алгоритм должен быть такой:

- читаете первый файл и сохраняете `ip` из него в множество (можно и в список, но когда список будет большой, искаться вхождение в нём будет долго)
- идёте по второму файлу и проверяете есть ли его `ip` в этом ранее заполненном множестве

```
ips = set()
with open("data/ips.txt") as prev_ip:
    for line in prev_ip:
        line = line.strip()
        ips.add(line)

open("data/ips1.txt") as cur_ip:
    for line in cur_ip:
        line = line.strip()
        if line not in ips:
            print(line)
```

Регулярные выражения тут вообще никак не нужны - вы же проверяете строки просто на совпадение.

Если вдруг в строках возможны лишние пробелы в начале или конце строки, то можно делать `line.strip()` перед добавлением в множество и перед поиском в множестве.

P.S. Добавил `strip()` в код.

Comment: спасибо за быстрый ответ , строки берутся с переводом строки, а в списке элемент идет как '10.0.0.1\n' , что по сути одно и то же, но почему то не идет совпадение. В случае с strip перенос обрезается, но он остается в списке

Comment: Приведите пример данных, на которых должно сработать. И у меня печатает **разницу**, если что, т.е. то, что **не нашлось**. В итоге печатает всё подряд или какой результат моего кода? Я добавил как использовать `strip` прямо в код.

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо что то не дописал, перепроверил, все работает, спасибо

Comment: Ну отлично )  Код у меня обычно простой и понятный, поэтому я в нём редко сомневаюсь )